# SOAP web service implementation method with @Autowired service gave null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, soap, spring-annotations

I am new for spring mvc with soap web service.

I have made one web project using spring-mvc, which has @Controller that can handle website view (using model). For business logic, have used @Service and @Repository class.

Now, I am making web service which has same business logic that is working for website view. For that I made one web service class and @Autowired existing @Service for business logic. But that @Autowired class referencing null.

Below is my sample project code, In which 
I have made service implementation class and autowired service class for business logic and tomcat catalina  **com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createResponse null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.springmvcmaven.ws.producer.hello.HelloWSImpl.hello(HelloWSImpl.java:34)**

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcmaven" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
  <endpoint implementation="com.springmvcmaven.ws.producer.hello.HelloWSImpl" name="hello" url-pattern="/hello"/>
</endpoints>
```

Model Class - User.java

```
  public class User
{
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Model Controller for web - HomeController.java

```
  @Controller
public class HomeController
{
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     * @param locale
     * @param model
     * @return 
     */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "homeService")
    @Lazy(true)
    private HomeService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("Home Page Requested, locale = " + locale);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String user(@Validated User user, Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("userName", service.wsCall(user));
        return "user";
    }
}
```

HomeService.java

```
  public interface HomeService
{
    public String wsCall(User user);
}
```

HomeServiceImpl.java

```
  @Service(value = "homeService")
public class HomeServiceImpl implements HomeService
{
    @Override
    public String wsCall(User user)
    {
        return "Bravo " + user.getUserName() + " !!";
    }   
}
```

Web service class interface - HelloWS.java

```
  @WebService(name="hello")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface HelloWS
{
    @WebMethod
    public String hello(User user);
}
```

web service implementation class - HelloWSImpl.java

```
  @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.springmvcmaven.ws.producer.hello.HelloWS")
public class HelloWSImpl implements HelloWS
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "homeService")
    @Lazy(true)
    private HomeService service;
    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     * @param user
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String hello(User user)
    {
        return service.wsCall(user);
    }
}

web service client call

    public class HelloClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCMaven/hello?wsdl");
            //check above URL in browser, you should see WSDL file

            //creating QName using targetNamespace and name
            QName qname = new QName("http://hello.producer.ws.springmvcmaven.com/", "HelloWSImplService"); 

            Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, qname);  

            //We need to pass interface and model beans to client
            HelloWS helloWS = service.getPort(HelloWS.class);
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserName("JIya");
            System.out.println(helloWS.hello(user));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION => \n" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly direct me, what I am missing from these code. Is this proper way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is that you are trying to do here in this line. Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, qname);  ??

Comment: creating web service client.. referred link -> https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thats fine. what I am asking is what is this 'Service' class ? Where is it coming from? I think thats where its throwing an exception. correcT?

Comment: no.. that is not the issue..have imported below classes.import com.springmvcmaven.model.User;
import com.springmvcmaven.ws.producer.hello.HelloWS;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service; Error is in HelloWSImpl (line no 34), which is autowired object.

Comment: Do you mean HelloWSImpl is the class which is trying to Autowrire HomeService in the name of 'service' variable and you have ws.Service as 'service' variable too ? Did you annotate the HomeService class with any ? Can you also post the component scanning path that you would have configured

Comment: check this out and try modifying your web.xml https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/

Comment: hello CrazyMac.. there is no duplication of service object.. code is.. javax.xml.ws.Service service = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(wsdlURL, qname); com.springmvcmaven.ws.producer.hello.HelloWS helloWS = service.getPort(com.springmvcmaven.ws.producer.hello.HelloWS.class);  component scanning is already mentioned above..<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcmaven" />

Comment: hello diedu.. I have already referred your suggested link.. but there are so many dependency classes so that I can't put all beans in dispatcher servlet.. and in dispatcher servlet class I have already put component scan..

Comment: did you find any answer to this ?